# Problem with scope in macro

Tags: macro, scope

I've written a short macro to get the first image inside a matrix field.

```
{% macro firstImage(entry) %}

    {% set image = 'hello' %}

    {% if entry.sliderMatrix.total() %}
        {% set block = entry.sliderMatrix|first %}
        {% set image = block.image|first %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ image.url }}

{% endmacro %}
```

The code throws this error: Impossible to access an attribute ("url") on a string variable ("hello")

`{{ image.url }}` inside the if statement works fine.

`{{ image }}` outside the if statement works too.

Is there anything I don't know or it's even a bug?

Comment: The code seems to be alright. Can you detail how your matrix is set up? Maybe a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is close, but not quite right and you're setting a variable as a string and later setting it as an Element Model. I think you're searching for something closer to this:

```
{% macro firstImage(entry) %}

    {% if entry.sliderMatrix.total() %}
        {% set block = entry.sliderMatrix.first %}
        {% set image = block.image.first %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if image is defined and image %}
        {{ image.url }}
    {% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: This syntax is much better! May I suggest `if image is defined`?

Comment: You surely may :-)

Comment: @Christian if that asset field is not marked as required you should also check if `first()` actually returns an image, so use this conditional `{% if image is defined and image %}`.

Comment: Even if that asset field **is** marked as required you should still check if `first()` actually returns an image. If that required image is deleted after the entry is created you will end up with an entry with no image.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to say for sure, but here's what I suspect... You may have multiple instances of `firstImage` being called from your main template.

For some of those instances, `entry.sliderMatrix.total` is **greater than** zero. For other instances, `entry.sliderMatrix.total` is **equal to** zero. And of course, when `entry.sliderMatrix.total` is equal to zero, your `if` statement will be bypassed.

Realistically, you shouldn't have the `image.url` call outside of your `if` statement. Because any time the `if` statement evaluates to *false*, then the `image` variable won't be what you want it to be. In fact, you'll get that exact error, since `image` will still be set to a string.